# String Output in Real-Mode by using LODS instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, real-mode

I'm need to write function, which output a string in real-mode.
There is that code:

```
;; ds:si - string address, cx - length of string
   cld
putc:
   lods
   mov ah, 0x0E
   xor bh, bh    
   int 0x10          ;; display character, advancing cursor and scrolling screen
                     ;; as necessary
   loop putc
```

But it output only first character few (defined by the CX register) times, a.e. the SI register don't increase.
Is where a error?

Comment: `lodsb` definitely does increment SI (since DF=0 after your `cld`).  SIngle-step your code in a debugger and look at registers (like AL) before each `int 0x10`, something else must be going on.  Are you sure the memory pointed-to by DS:SI holds what you expect?  I assume your assembler assembles `lods` to `lodsb` despite the ambiguous operand-size?  If not, perhaps it just treated it as a label, not an instruction?  NASM warns by default about labels without a `:` for that reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lods` isn't a valid instruction mnemonic; you probably mean `lodsb`.

On my assembler (nasm), a token that isn't a valid mnemonic gets parsed as a label instead, and so no code is emitted.  Thus your `lods` is effectively a no-op, so no wonder SI doesn't increment.  (The assembler does give a warning though, does yours?)

Comment: Yes, it work, when put lodsb instead lods. Strangely NASM doesn't emit warning (or error). Also the 8086's Family Intel Manual tell "lods" instruction, but there isn't a word about "lodsb" or "lodsw". Thanks for help

Comment: @SubtRose: With Intel's original ASM-86 assembler, I believe you could write the string instructions with operands, whose types would inform the assembler what size to use.  E.g. `wordvar dw ...` ; `lods wordvar` would load bytes.  There are some examples on page 2-125 and following.  This usage is now unusual and many assemblers probably don't support it at all.  Even ASM-86 apparently supported the `movsb` syntax too, see page 2-114.

Comment: @SubtRose: What version of nasm are you using?  2.14.02 warns `lods.asm:5: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+orphan-labels]`